# returning Html in a controller symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and i need to use Curl to return Html from a Webservice, i tried to simply `return $html` , but Symfony2 fired :

> Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template ""

any help will be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
class Controller
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Hello</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition of Muhammad Faizan Uddin answer, don't forget to add

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

in top of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

A controller in Symfony must always return a Response object.